how can i get latest version property from spring cloud config server with vault backend
I'm teaching myself the Spring Cloud Config Server with Vault Server as Backend and having some trouble with getting the properties by spring cloud config server HTTP API.
[spring cloud config server]
spring cloud config server is running on 127.0.0.1:8888 port.
property file is as follows:
application.yml
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  profiles:
    active: vault
  application:
    name: config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        vault:
          host: 127.0.0.1
          port: 8200
          token: ~
          scheme: http
          kv-version: 2
          backend: secret
          authentication: token
          order: 1

and, Vault server's foo metadata is as follows:
http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secret/data/foo
{
    "request_id": "cb7af252-6f1d-25a5-3329-dec2b2458560",
    "lease_id": "",
    "renewable": false,
    "lease_duration": 0,
    "data": {
        "data": {
            "foo": "bar"
        },
        "metadata": {
            "created_time": "2024-04-16T06:38:38.523582886Z",
            "custom_metadata": null,
            "deletion_time": "",
            "destroyed": false,
            "version": 5
        }
    },
    "wrap_info": null,
    "warnings": null,
    "auth": null,
    "mount_type": "kv"
}

i want to get "foo" property with version through spring cloud config server HTTP API call,
but HTTP response body's version info is null.
for Details,
HTTP GET :: http://{config-server}/foo/default
Response Body :
{
  "name": "foo",
  "profiles": [
    "default"
  ],
  "label": null,
  "version": null, <------------
  "state": null,
  "propertySources": [
    {
      "name": "vault:foo",
      "source": {
        "foo": "bar"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Expecting Response,
{
  "name": "foo",
  "profiles": [
    "default"
  ],
  "label": null,
  "version": 5, <-------- latest version
  "state": null,
  "propertySources": [
    {
      "name": "vault:foo",
      "source": {
        "foo": "bar"
      }
    }
  ]
}

So, My question is how can i get property file with version info from spring cloud config server HTTP API ?
